# How can I set a variable to API data without getting undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to set 'shareUrl' equal to a hardcoded url interpolated with an id which is returned from an API using fetch in an async function. However, it keeps throwing the error that shareUrl is undefined.

```
function Recipe() {

  let params = useParams();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('summary');
  const [borderRadius, setBorderRadius] = useState(15);
  let shareUrl;
  

  const fetchDetails = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${params.name}/information?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`);
    const detailData = await data.json();
    setDetails(detailData);
    shareUrl = `https://dishlyst.netlify.app/recipe/${details.id}`;
    return shareUrl;
  }
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDetails();
  }, [params.name]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      {window.screen.width < 760 ? setBorderRadius(15) : setBorderRadius(0)}
  }, []);

  // console.log(Object.keys(details), 'details')

  return (
    <DetailWrapper>
        <h2>{details.title}</h2>
        
        <ButtonImageContainer>
          <ShareContainerOuter>
          <img src={details.image} alt={details.title} />
          
            <ShareButtonsContainer>
              <ShareIconContainer>
                <BsShareFill/>
              </ShareIconContainer>
              <PinterestShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
              <TwitterShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
              <FacebookShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
              <LineShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
              <LinkedInShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
              <WhatsAppShareBtn borderRadius={borderRadius} shareUrl={shareUrl}/>
            </ShareButtonsContainer>
          </ShareContainerOuter>
```

Comment: It can't be done without state or ref. Please read react tutorial

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?